# MYSQL: after using SUBSTRING_INDEX my data change/corrupt (rtl language)

Tags: mysql, indexing, substring, right-to-left, persian

After using `substring_index` on a column, my data changes or corrupts the non-English text in the field, which is in Persian. I also checked the collation and charset and it is UTF-8.

If I use English, it works like a charm, but in rtl languages it doesn't work. Here is my record before `substring`:

```
select group_id , rows from concat
```

[image: before]

Here is what I get after `substring_index`:

```
select group_id , SUBSTRING_INDEX(rows, ',', 1) as name from concat
```

[image: after]

It shows "A+3" but 
It should show "فثس".

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Maybe I`m seeing things but are you sure that is a comma?Copy it from your data directly into SUBSTRING_INDEX separator to test it.

Comment: @Mihai, yes it is, the field is created with mysql "group_concat" function.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out; The problem was after using `substring_index` the field type changes to "MEDIUMBLOB" which causes the problem.
so I did converted it and now it works.

```
select group_id , CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rows, ',', 1), CHAR(1000)) as name from concat
```